# How do I access the row values when importing a file with Django Import-Export?

Tags: django, django-import-export

I am importing a file with django import-export and I want to take the values of each row.

For example:

```
import_resource = ImportResource()
dataset = Dataset()
imported_data = dataset.load(import_file.read().decode('utf-8'))
result = import_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)
```

I iterate through the rows of the Result with `result.rows` and each row seems to have a `raw_values` property but it returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the code below.

```
class OtherResource(resources.ModelResource):
    """
    My code
    """               
    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        row['created_by'] = kwargs.get('user')
        row['modified_by'] = kwargs.get('user')

class MyClassAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):

    resource_class = OtherResource

    def import_data(self, dataset, dry_run=False, raise_errors=False, use_transactions=None, collect_failed_rows=False, **kwargs):
        """
        Getting the user's request to pass it to the import
        """
        result = OtherResource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False, raise_errors=False, use_transactions=None, user=self.request.user)
        return result
```

You have to remember there are a lot of actions such as: before_import_row, after_import_row among others.